# Limit TortoiseHg Workbench history to specific branches only

Tags: tortoisehg

I wonder if there is a revision set query for TortoiseHg filter that would limit the revision history to specific branches only.

For example, I have two people working at the same time on two different code features. They both create many revisions, and both work in a couple of branches each. Their commits are shown mixed together in the revision history.

Is it possible to include, e.g. only branches "A" and "B" but not "C"? Also, can I use wildcards?

I would typically include branches "feature-1*", "test" and "release" for user 1 and "feature-2*", "test" and "release" for user 2. Here "*" means that a user can create sub-branches while working on a feature, and wants to see all his sub-branches.

**Update:** I am aware of the "Branch" dropdown in the Filter toolbar. It allows showing a *single* branch. I would like to see *multiple* branches. 
I think I need to use a "branch" query command, but I am not sure what I would pass as its argument.

I am also aware of the documentation at https://www.mercurial-scm.org/doc/hg.1.html#revsets, but I fail to understand how to set up a query I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click the filter button (the white funnel in the toolbar), then specify the query in the text field:

```
branch('re:feature-1.*') or branch(test)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this "or" was what I was missing. Was lost between strings and sets.

Comment: In some versions of Hg Workbench, the icon is a magnifying glass.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up filters in the workbench by displaying the filter toolbar (View menu => Filter toolbar). To the right of the new toolbar there is an option called "branch" which lets you filter on any (named) branch while ignoring all other revisions. This setting is even persistent if you close and reopen the workbench.

The very same toolbar includes a search bar that may be of some use to you, but not sure how many wildcards it does accept.

Comment: Thanks, I've played with that branch dropdown, but it allows selecting one branch only. I need to show several branches, e.g. "release", "test", "feature A".